# How to prevent JavaScript from hotlinking and direct access?

Tags: apache

How to prevent JavaScript from hotlinking and direct access? With .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

This script works for me. Hope its useful to you too:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)yoursite.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(js)$ - [F]
```